# How to fetch incremental data from Databricks delta table?

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake

We are refreshing data on daily basis to our delta table. Now we need to push only incremental data to S3 (not full data) from previous run.

How to take incremental data into Dataframe?

we are setting below property to out table so we can get new version after each update.

```
ALTER TABLE <table name> SET TBLPROPERTIES (delta.enableChangeDataFeed = true)"""
```

[image]

***Can we use these versions to get incremental backup? How? Any sample code?***

Comment: You can query `table_change()` -- see: [Use Delta Lake change data feed on Azure Databricks - Azure Databricks | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/delta/delta-change-data-feed)

Comment: Using table_change() giving me double records instead of giving incremental difference... it returns more data than original table :(

Comment: That's strange. It should only give you the difference between two versions by using `table_changes('tableName', 1, 2)`. Does _that_ give 'more data than the original table' if you specify the two most recent versions?

Comment: Yeah, e.g. table_changes('tableName', 7, 8)... I am using df.count() to check total records after this.... original table had 1billion+ records and after using table_changes('tableName', 7, 8) it's giving me 3billion records

Comment: spark.sql("SELECT * FROM table_changes('tablename', 7, 8) order by _commit_timestamp")

Comment: It might be because the data changed multiple times between versions 7 and 8. Pick one Primary Key and take a look at the `table_changes()` displayed. That should give you a hint as to what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this is to use [Delta Deep Clone functionality](https://docs.databricks.com/en/sql/language-manual/delta-clone.html) - no need to enable Change Data Feed, etc.  You can find some information in the documentation and [this blog post](https://www.databricks.com/blog/2020/09/15/easily-clone-your-delta-lake-for-testing-sharing-and-ml-reproducibility.html). And, for example, it's often [used for Disaster Recovery](https://www.databricks.com/blog/2021/04/20/attack-of-the-delta-clones-against-disaster-recovery-availability-complexity.html).  You just need to execute:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE table_name
DEEP CLONE source_table_name LOCATION 's3://....
```

The only caveat is that right now Deep Clone doesn't preserve individual history entries if you had multiple transactions between clones, but that shouldn't matter much for backups.

If you need detailed changes, then you can enable Change Data Feed, and consume data in the streaming manner (see [docs](https://docs.databricks.com/en/delta/delta-change-data-feed.html#read-changes-in-streaming-queries)), but it will be different table, with its own history, etc.

Comment: how to store this difference/delta to new dataframe... we wont to perform operations on that df object only

Comment: Ok, if you need to have diff, then CDF is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that multiple changes are happening between versions and `table_changes()` is returning *all* of the changes between those two versions.

If you only want the 'latest version' of the changes, then you could do something like:

```sql
select * from table
where primary_key in (select primary_key from table_changes('table', 2, 3))
```

That will return the 'current' row for any primary key that changed during that period.